# How to use a database created in an app in some other app

Tags: android, database, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access database of another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747225/access-database-of-another-app)

I made an app which is a broadcastreceiver, and inside it I have an sqlite database (say X) created. 
I created database using DatabaseHelper which extends SQLiteOpenHelper.

Now i want to use this database X in my another app. How is it done?

The database X is dynamic, i.e. entries are added as some broadcast is received so this dynamic behavior should be kept in another app too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up about ContentProviders. It might be a little tricky to build a content provider over a dynamic data set, but it's definitely possible.